# One-liner to create a data.frame and have columns depend on each other

Tags: r, dataframe

A not-uncommon situation in generating data.frames (particularly for SO questions which are not reproducible) is when one column depends on the (typically random) values of another.  For instance, if one wants a data.frame to test regression on, it would be great to have some noisy linear dependence:

```
n <- 100
x <- runif(n)
dat <- data.frame( x=x, y=x+runif(n) )
plot(y~x,data=dat)
```

[image: y vs x]

However, I'd like to do it in one line (the above would count as two lines, the first creating x, the second using x in the data.frame assignment), ideally without depositing anything in the global environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an easy solution with `within`:

```
within(data.frame(x = runif(n)), y <- x + runif(n))
```

This command does *not* assign `y` to the global environment (or parent frame).

Comment: Lots of creative answers, but I think this and @WojciechSobala come the closest to how I think about the world.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way that does not break the "one-assignment-per-line" rule a lot of programmers like to stick to:

```
within(data.frame(row.names = 1:n), {x = runif(n); y = x + runif(n)})
```

where `data.frame(row.names = 1:n)` is used to create an empty data.frame with the right number of rows, otherwise `within` would complain.

Comment: This solution depends on `x` already being created. Otherwise, R would complain.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein, you are correct, I missed that. I replaced `transform` with a similar `within` version that does not have the issue.

Comment: `plyr::mutate` works the same way as a transform, except that you can refer to columns you just created.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that suffers neither of the two downsides you ID'd.

```
library(data.table)
n <- 100

dat <- data.table(x = runif(n))[, y := x + runif(n)]
```

Its own downsides are:

1. Requires loading an entire package.
2. Becomes a bit uglier (i.e. `data.frame(data.table(......))` if you want a "plain-old" `data.frame` returned.

Answer (score 3):

`set.seed` will be needed to make the random numbers reproducible in any case but modulo that try this:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- transform(data.frame(x = runif(10)), y = x + runif(10))
```

This gives:

```
> dat
           x         y
1  0.2875775 1.2444109
2  0.7883051 1.2416393
3  0.4089769 1.0865476
4  0.8830174 1.4556508
5  0.9404673 1.0433920
6  0.0455565 0.9453815
7  0.5281055 0.7741932
8  0.8924190 0.9344786
9  0.5514350 0.8793557
10 0.4566147 1.4111184
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a custom function that works like `transform` (or `plyr::mutate`), but doesn't require an initial data frame.  (Obviously this doesn't really help with the OP's question since no one will have this function, but I thought others might be interested anyway)

```
create <- function(...) {
  .data <- list()

  cols <- as.list(substitute(list(...))[-1])
  cols <- cols[names(cols) != ""] # Silently drop unnamed columns

  for(col in names(cols)) {
    .data[[col]] <- eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame())
  }
  as.data.frame(.data)
}
create(x = runif(1:10), y = x + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best I've come up with.  It uses something that is a common mistake from beginner R folks as a trick to write more compact code.

```
dat <- data.frame( x<-runif(n), y=x+runif(n) )
```

This is similar in spirit to [@Tommy's tip on CodeGolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4051/3163).

Downsides are:

1. Potentially confusing.  Especially so since it's such a common mistake, and might be confused by an expert code reviewer with a mistake in this case.
2. Deposits `x` in the parent (global, in most use cases) environment, where it might overwrite some other variable.

**Edit**

@WojciechSobala's solution in the comment deserves highlighting here.  Simply wrap the above expression in `local`:

```
dat <- local( data.frame( x<-runif(n), y=x+runif(n) ) )
```

Since `local` works just like `evalq` (e.g. it evaluates an expression in a given environment) except that it by default evaluates in a new environment via `new.env()`, `x` gets created in this new environment not in the global environment.

Comment: you can modify your code to remove downsides: dat <- local({data.frame(x= x<-runif(n), y= x+runif(n))})